# difference between libc6-dev and libc6

Tags: glibc

`libc6-dev:amd64` package in Debian contains all the common header files in C programming like `stdio.h`, `ctype.h`, `time.h`, etc. Am I correct that `libc6:amd64`, which is as far as I know required by virtually any application written in C, contains those same header file in compiled form? Or in short, how are `libc6-dev:amd64` and `libc6:amd64` different?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out the package descriptions; for [`libc6`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libc6):

> Contains the standard libraries that are used by nearly all programs on the system. This package includes shared versions of the standard C library and the standard math library, as well as many others.

and for [`libc6-dev`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libc6-dev):

> Contains the symlinks, headers, and object files needed to compile and link programs which use the standard C library.

`libc6` provides the functionality implemented by the C library, in the form of several shared libraries (`libc.so.6` etc.). `libc6-dev` provides extra files which are needed to build software using the C library; those extra files are different from the contents of the shared libraries.

Another way of thinking about this is that `libc6` provides the files needed at runtime, for programs using the C library, and `libc6-dev` provides the files needed at build time, on top of the library itself (which is why `libc6-dev` depends on `libc6` — you need both to build software). `libc6` contains files used by the dynamic linker to run software built with the C library, `libc6-dev` contains files used by the compiler and build-time linker to build software using the C library.

The same distinction applies to most library packages; you’ll find a runtime package, and a build-time `-dev` package.

Comment: Thanks for reply! So for example if I write a program in C where I include for example `stdio.h` header file(provided by `libc6-dev` package) and compile this program, then this compiled program now requires `libc.so.6` shared library(provided by `libc6`)?

Comment: Unless you go out of your way to avoid it, all compiled C programs need the C library (try compiling a program with just a `main()` containing `return 0;`). But `stdio.h` does come from `libc6-dev`, yes. The distinction really is build-time versus runtime; you can write programs which need header files to build but have no resulting runtime dependencies (look for [single-file libraries](https://github.com/nothings/single_file_libs)), and you can also write programs which have a runtime dependency on a library without needing the corresponding headers at build time.

Comment: However your understanding is a decent start ;-).