# Why do I have libc.so.6 under /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu directory?

Tags: linux, glibc

After I read this question [difference between libc6-dev and libc6](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/379711/difference-between-libc6-dev-and-libc6) , I started a fresh `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS` VPS and went checking what files are included in some Ubuntu packages.

I checked `libc6-dev` (https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/libc6-dev/filelist) and `libc6` (https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/libc6/filelist).

As we can see, the `libc6-dev` have those share libraries under `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` and `libc6` 's share libraries are under `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`.

But what makes me curious is that:

1. I also have `libc.so.6`  under `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` (`libc.so.6 -> libc-2.31.so*`). And `apt install remove libc6-dev` doesn't remove `libc.so.6`. Where does this `libc.so.6` come from?
2. The `-rw-r--r--  1 root root  298 Apr  7 09:24 libc.so` installed by `libc6-dev` packge is only `298` bytes, what? Why?

`sudo apt list --installed` output: https://pastebin.com/geDjY2z2
`ll -h | grep libc` output: https://pastebin.com/UHn5QVt1

`ll -h | grep libc` output, left(remove `libc6-dev`):

[image: text]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`libc.so.6` is part of the `libc6` package. It is only in the file list in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, but `/lib` is a symlink to `/usr/lib`, so it shows up in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` as well. `libc.so.6` is the library which programs using the C library refer to:

```
$ ldd /bin/true
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc797a9000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc865f4a000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc86614b000)
```

`libc.so` is used when building programs, and [is a linker script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/403997/86440) rather than a library; you can examine its contents:

```
$ cat /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so
/* GNU ld script
   Use the shared library, but some functions are only in
   the static library, so try that secondarily.  */
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf64-x86-64)
GROUP ( /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a  AS_NEEDED ( /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ) )
```

Comment: God I didn't even notice that `/lib` is a symlink to `/usr/lib`, now it all makes sense. Thank you so much, you are the saviour of this site. 

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS,  /lib is not a symlink to /usr/lib